# Access Azure Instance Metadata Service (169.254.169.254) from Windows docker container

Tags: azure, docker, networking, containers

Azure VM can query the [Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service) located at `169.254.159.254` for data. However this does not work from within a Windows container running on the VM.

How can a Windows container query the Instance Metadata Service that's only accessible from the host VM?

For example when using a Windows container like this: `docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`

And querying for data like this: `Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method GET -Uri http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-06-01`

Results in this:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -Method GET -Uri http ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that we can't access the Azure Instance Metadata Service endpoint from the Windows container on the Azure VM because the container on the docker is isolated within a different network from the VM network and the IMDS is only available from a non-routable IP address from within the VM level.

> Azure's IMDS is a REST Endpoint that is available at a well-known
> non-routable IP address (169.254.169.254), it can be accessed only
> from within the VM. **Communication between the VM and IMDS never leaves
> the Host.**

and

> The Instance Metadata Service endpoint is accessible only from within
> the running virtual machine instance on a non-routable IP address. In
> addition, any request with an `X-Forwarded-For` header is rejected by the
> service.

The following diagram describes the integrated Containers with your existing VM. Get more details [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/containers-replacing-virtual-machines/).

[image]

When you generate a containerized application on the Azure VM, the container communicates with the outside of this container via a default docker virtualized nat NIC. For example, on the Azure VM, there is an extra IP address `172.22.48.1` used for docker instances connecting with guest OS in the network `172.18.4.0/24`.

[image]

### Edit

From [Known issues and FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service#known-issues-and-faq),

> Metadata calls must be made from the primary IP address assigned to
> the primary network card of the VM.

When you call metadata from your container on the Azure VM, it's actually using a NAT nic (it's having a different MAC address from primary nic)instead of the primary nic.

Comment: The [l2bridge network driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/network-drivers-topologies#l2bridge-network-driver) rewrites traffic MAC address. Would that be able to contact the metadata service?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that specific driver, but the question can be answered generically. As a result of the network layout, IMDS has no insight into how a request is generated from within the VM. All it cares about is that the request comes from that Primary NIC + Primary IP.

As long as the virtual network is eventually routing the request over that interface, it will work. Based on the answer below, it sounds like that is indeed what happens

Just be mindful that you're running trusted code in the docker container, as bridging the network will give access to any MSI tokens for that VM.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reach IMDS via an l2bridge (tried on a 2022 datacenter server). Create the network as

```
docker network create -d l2bridge --subnet $localContainerSubnet -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.dnsservers=$dnsServer --gateway $containerGw -o com.docker.network.windowsshim.enable_outboundnat=true <network_name>
```

where the variables `$dnsServer`, `$localContainerSubnet`, `$containerGw` are the same as the host's network (subnet is in CIDR format).

For details see this [blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/l2bridge-container-networking/ba-p/1180923) and [comment](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/l2bridge-container-networking/bc-p/1471840/highlight/true#M280) on creating an l2bridge on the same subnet.

After creating the network run the container with `--network <network_name>`.